# Unable to solve error generated while referring textbox to get table data in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I use the below VBA Code to get the data from a table, it returns a '#Name?' Error.

=DLookUp("[Material Description]","employeeDetails","[employeeDetails]![Material Code] = " & [Text0])

is there a solution to this problem?.
[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is mainly because you are actually having a Syntax error, but as you are using a Unbound Text Box's control source so the error is hidden to display a `#Name` error. If you are using VBA, you would use the Form Current event.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.yourTextBoxName = DLookup("[Material Description]", _
                                 "employeeDetails", "[Material Code] = '" & [Text0] & "'")
    'If Material code is Number type, then use.
    'Me.yourTextBoxName = DLookup("[Material Description]", _
                                 "employeeDetails", "[Material Code] = " & [Text0])
End Sub
```